# Import users from LDAP AD to geofence

Tags: active-directory, ldap, geoserver, geofencing

I want to import users from LDAP server (Active Directory) to Geofence, for that I started by setting up my LDAP server then I configured Geofence with the LDAP server and I added the LDAP module as shown here https://github.com/geoserver/geofence/wiki/LDAP-module, but it does not work.
Do you have any suggestions for it to work?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: what doesn't work? what does the log file say?

Comment: The import of users from AD doesn't work, and there is no error in the log file that's why i can't find the problem . I configured LDAP Server like this  [ LDAP server configuration ] (https://github.com/geoserver/geofence/wiki/GeoFence-configuration#ldap-server-configuration)